# crux framework error mvn gwt:compile

Tags: gwt

I've download sample [crux](http://www.cruxframework.org) projects from https://code.google.com/p/crux-framework/source/checkout
and compile subproject crux-site but i've this error:

```
crux-site $ mvn clean package
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL

crux-site $ mvn gwt:compile 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO] Compiling module org.cruxframework.cruxsite.CruxSite
[ERROR] mar 17, 2015 6:17:02 PM org.cruxframework.crux.core.rebind.DevelopmentScanners initializeScanners
[ERROR] INFORMAZIONI: Registering scanners for crux compilation...
[ERROR] mar 17, 2015 6:17:03 PM org.cruxframework.crux.core.server.CruxBridge handleCriticalError
[ERROR] GRAVE: CruxBridge critical error: Error getting lastPageRequestedFile.
[ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/screenRequestedBridgeFile (No such file or directory)
[ERROR]     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
....
```

i've not modify initial sources, the error is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/screenRequestedBridgeFile

my system is: ubuntu 14.04, maven 2, jdk oracle 7

any idea?

---

ok Thiago, now i compile app and view it on browser, but the problem is while recompile in super dev mode. I got same problem

Compiling module org.cruxframework.cruxsite.CruxSite
mar 18, 2015 11:31:38 PM

```
org.cruxframework.crux.core.rebind.DevelopmentScanners initializeScanners
INFORMAZIONI: Registering scanners for crux compilation...
mar 18, 2015 11:31:39 PM org.cruxframework.crux.core.server.CruxBridge handleCriticalError
GRAVE: CruxBridge critical error: Error getting lastPageRequestedFile.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/screenRequestedBridgeFile (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

(compile in super dev mode is on browser, refreshing page when java source is modified)

Answer (score 0):

To compile a crux application with maven, you can not use the gwt:compile goal.

To generate the war file, try to call mvn install instead.

For debug, you can try the eclipse launch files StartCodeServer.launch and StartJetty.launch (on Eclipse IDE) and then open the url (http://localhost:8080/cruxsite/index.html) on browser.

---

EDIT

I could not reproduce your problem. Anyway, can you try to change the cruxVersion property on pom.xml to point to 5.3.0-SNAPSHOT?

The reason for this is that CodeServer should not was trying to read this file. On 5.3.0 version we fix this behaviour. This file is only used when application is using the old GWT DevMode now.

5.3.0, however was not released yet, but will be very soon, in the next few days. So, you will need to use this SNAPSHOT for the moment.

Comment: i've updated my post, now compile but i've error in recompile in super dev mode